# Remove duplicates from a list, excluding start and end

Tags: python, list

Is there more pythonic way to remove all duplicate elements from a list, while keeping the first and last element?

```
lst = ["foo", "bar", "foobar", "foo", "barfoo", "foo"]

occurence = [i for i, e in enumerate(lst) if e == "foo"]

to_remove = occurence[1:-1]
for i in to_remove:
    del lst[i]

print(lst) # ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'barfoo', 'foo']
```

Another approach which I like more.

```
for i, e in enumerate(lst[1:-1]): 
    if e == "foo": 
        del lst[i+1]
```

Comment: All of these approaches are inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a slice-assignment and unpack/consume a filter?

```
lst = ["foo", "bar", "foobar", "foo", "barfoo", "foo"]

lst[1:-1] = filter(lambda x: x != "foo", lst[1:-1])
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'barfoo', 'foo']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a new list with your requirements using Python's set data structure and slicing like this:

```
lst = ["foo", "bar", "foobar", "foo", "barfoo", "foo"]
new_lst = [lst[0]] + list(set(lst[1:-1])) + [lst[-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
lst = ["foo", "bar", "foobar", "foo", "barfoo", "foo"]

first, last = lst[0], lst[-1]
seen = {first, last}
seen_add = seen.add

inner = (s for s in lst[1:-1] if not (s in seen or seen_add(s)))
result = [first, *inner, last]
```

Result:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'barfoo', 'foo']
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, it's necessary to remove the duplicates looking at the entire list and then adding the first and last elements:

```
lst = ["foo", "bar", "foobar", "foo", "barfoo", "foo"]

first, last = lst[0], lst[-1]
data = [first, *set([w for w in lst if w not in [first, last]]), last]

print(data)
```

Output:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'barfoo', 'foobar', 'foo']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
mylist = ["foo", "bar", "foobar", "foo", "barfoo", "foo"]
none_duplicated = list(dict.fromkeys(mylist))
print([mylist[0], *none_duplicated, mylist[-1]])
```

Actually, your question is not about to remove duplicates, but remove the occurrences of your first item in the list (assume first and last are the same). But if you want a more generic way, you will first try to get a list of none duplicated value, and then add your first and last.